# Yii2. Ошибка при подключение стороннего класса

Tags: yii2

Как правильно подключить сторонний класс? А точнее это не класс а (библиотека)файл с несколькими классами. Использовать один из классов этой библиотеки нужно в контроллере.
Полный путь к файлу salvagedata\vendor\SalvageData\AjaxController\ProjectsController

подключил его в своём контроллере с помощю

```
use SalvageData\AjaxController\ProjectsController;
```

Затем обращаюсь к нему `$salvageProjectController = new ProjectsController();`

И получаю ошибку 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать в данной ситуации?

Comment: Добрый вечер. А что это за пакет? Можете ссылку дать?

Comment: Думаю, что Ваша проблема в регистре названий классов. Есть в пакете файл readme? Посмотрите там.

Comment: Нету, эти файлы сделаны для работы с vtiger, чтобы срабатывал workflow и т.п. Я от туда использую функции.

Comment: Вы просто скопировали нужные файлы в vendor? Или где эти файлы находятся?

Comment: В корне сайта папка salvagedata, затем в ней идет vendor, это не vendor  
yii2 установленного через composer. Salvagedata я просто скопировал и вставил в проект.

Comment: Нужно перенести в какую либо другую директорию, ту, что известна yii2. Например "components" и уже от туда подключать. Или создавайте псевдоним для "salvagedata" прописывайте в конфигах и тогда будет видно эту директорию. И видеть бы структуру этих директорий, было бы вообще хорошо.

Comment: http://image.ibb.co/dAwG0x/struktura.png

В скриншоте указана структура.

Comment: Так вряд ли у Вас что-то получится. Или пробовать делать как я писал выше или вообще, оформлять отдельным модулем. Yii ничего не знает о Вашей директории.

Comment: Исправил, если интересно как я оставил комментарий снизу.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил. Если кому будет интересно. 
в файле composer.json пишите

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Главный namespace": "директория к нему/",

        }

    }

composer dump-autoload
```

и всё будет работать!

Comment: Как вариант вполне. Забыл про него, когда комментарий писал)))